# Get last 30 days from table in SQL with YYYY-MM-DDtHH-MM-SS (BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery, I have a table of values with one column containing dates in YYYY-MM-DDtHH-MM-SS format, for example, 2020-07-24T20:13:35.

I want to pull only the rows from the past 30 days and exclude any rows that are more than 30 days old.

I believe I found out how to do it for date formatted as YYYY-MM-DD:
(Column name is "dates")

SELECT DATE_SUB(dates, INTERVAL 30 DAY)

This does not work when it is formatted as YYYY-MM-DDtHH-MM-SS though.

Answer (score 2):

You would simply use:

```
where col > datetime_add(current_datetime, interval -30 day)
```

or

```
where col > timestamp_add(current_timestamp, interval -30 day)
```

depending on whether the column is a `datetime` or `timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
Select * from table where date(date_column) >= date_sub(current_date, interval 30 day)
```

This way you will get all the records from 30 days before, starting from 12am. Using current_datetime or current_timestamp will only give results later than 30 days ago at time you run your query.